# Background image overlay

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to insert image in div with CSS as background-image:

```
.our-service-list-card.width-big.height-big  {
flex-basis: 652px;
background-image: url(../assets/img/Card1.svg);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
```

I also have color change with hovering over it:

```
.our-service-list-card:hover {
background-color: #6FF5EA;
transition: 0.3s; }
```

The only way I found this hovering effect can be achieved on top of/including this image is with

```
background-blend-mode: overlay; 
background-blend-mode: lighten;
```

But I feel that there's different of simpler solution for this which I'm missing.

Is there any other way to make this image overlayed with background-image method ?

Answer (score 0):

you could try using after element with the background color and applying opacity if you like